# counting number of roots with Bolzano theorem

Tags: roots

I have 2 Questions:

1. How to get the roots of the equation f (x) = 0 using Bolzano theorem? (f is a continuous function and we dont know its type(polynomial or else))
2. How can the above algorithm be improved to count the number of double roots?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq) to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. As this question appears to be homework, please consider reading [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803) for information about asking _effective_ homework-related questions.

Comment: Give a reference to the theorem by Bolzano you are refering to. Besides, is $f$ continuous, is $f$ any function or a polynomial ? There is a place for improvement in the way your question is formulated, moreover without showing any personal work on the question

Comment: I edited my question. f is continuous and we don't know its type.

Comment: 1) Reference [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BolzanosTheorem.html) (It is only in some parts of the world where this result is known under the name "Bolzano's theorem") 2) The algorithm you are looking for must use a tuned version of [Bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method)